# Screensaver that is a pop3 client

Tags: email, screensaver

I am looking for a screen saver that will notify me when an email comes into my pop3 in-box and shows me the subject field.

I do paperwork sometimes, and it'd be nice to be able to look up and go, "oh, hey, an email that I (need)|(don't need) to deal with".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  [ePrompter](http://www.eprompter.com)     email notification program  automatically and simultaneously checks and retrieves your email messages from up to sixteen password protected email accounts such as AIM, AOL, Hotmail, Yahoo, Yahoo Beta, Earthlink, Excite, Juno, Lycos, Mail.com, Mindspring, MSN, MSN Live Mail, MyWay, Netscape, POP3, Rediffmail, SBC Yahoo, USA.net and hundreds of other email domains.